# What is the Run prompt equivalency in Linux?

Tags: samba, command, desktop-environment

In Windows, there is the Run prompt, which you can access with Win+R key.

[image: run]

What is the equivalency to this in Linux? Is there even such a thing or is the Terminal the main prompt you would use in Linux for the type of tasks you normally use the Run prompt for in Windows?

Here is a use case. I want to access `\\192.168.0.103\` on my home network. On Windows, I can use the Run prompt for this. Like so:

[image: run2]

Where do you type in UNC paths and how do you access them on Linux? What do I have to consider if the remote is a Windows based computer? Do I have to spend a day or two configuring things or will it just work out of the box? You know... SMB, Samba and all that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on which desktop environment you are using.

In [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/), [KDE](http://www.kde.org/), [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) and [Xfce](http://xfce.org/) the default keyboard shortcut for the run prompt is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

As [jofel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92953/43779) pointed out, `xdg-open` is a desktop-independent tool for opening a file or URL in a preferred application. Inside a desktop environment, `xdg-open` simply passes the arguments to a desktop environment specific equivalent (`gvfs-open` in GNOME and Unity, `kde-open` in KDE or `exo-open` in Xfce).

While the desktop environments [might](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446136) [not](http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316222) support UNC paths, they generally do understand [URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier). Since in this case you want to access a Windows [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) share, the corresponding URI scheme is `smb`, yielding an URI like `smb://192.168.0.103`.

Generally you should be able to pass an URI like this to `xdg-open`, either in the run prompt or in a shell running in a terminal emulator, and have `xdg-open` open the specified URI in the preferred application associated with the particular URI scheme:

```
xdg-open smb://192.168.0.103
```

In the case of GNOME, which is the default desktop environment in Debian, this would, by default, be the [Nautilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_(file_manager)) file manager. Unfortunately it seems that there is a [possible](https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/311620/comments/2) [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21728) with `xdg-open`, which prevents the opening of SMB shares, unless they have been mounted beforehand. This should be handled by the [*Gnome Virtual File System*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) (GVFS) automatically, but for some reason it might not work with `xdg-open`.

As a workaround, you could pass the URI directly to `nautilus` in the Run prompt (or shell). Alternatively you could open the SMB share via the **Connect to server** dialog in Nautilus (File > Connect to Server) or type the `smb` URI in the **Location** bar (Go > Location or triggered via the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

Comment: I think it's Gnome. It's Debian 7.1.0 Wheezy, the default environment I think.

Comment: It works! I see a "Run Application" dialog box. But unfortunately accessing UNC paths is not as simple as typing in `\\192.168.0.103` and hitting Enter, like on Windows. If I do that, it says "could not open location". Should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: If you're using gnome, UNC paths probably won't work, but you can try running `xdg-open` giving the destination URI as argument.

Comment: Yeah, `smb://192.168.0.102` didn't work. Is says "could not open location" and "file doesn't exist". It's the same with `cifs:\\192.168.0.103` as suggested by @jofel except it now says "the specified location is not supported".

Comment: So you mean like `xdg-open smb:\\192.168.0.103` and I type that in the Run Application prompt? Or the Terminal?...

Comment: Well I tried the Run prompt first, the dialog box just closes (as it's supposed to) when I hit Enter but there is no response. Not even an error. While in Terminal I get a response like "the specified location is not supported" and so and so forth. I tried variations, like cifs instead of smb, and only typing the UNC and only the IP, nothing works. I will have to post this as a separate question.

Comment: You have your slashes and backslashes mixed up. URIs have slashes (`/`). You also cannot omit the protocol part as that is used by `xdg-open` to determine the preferred application to launch.

Comment: Ah! You noticed that! Thanks! So it would be `xdg-open smb:\\192.168.0.103` then? There is no space between semicolon and backslash?

Comment: Exactly the opposite: `xdg-open smb://192.168.0.103`. No space between semicolon and backslash.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10822/discussion-between-sammy-and-thomas-nyman)

Comment: I think [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/) defaults to binding Alt+F2 to this, too. I'm pretty sure xfrun4 only accepts proper commands, though (that's all I use it for).

Answer (score 1):

Under most window managers you get a similar prompt by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

It depends on your environment, if you can enter UNC/URLs/paths or only real commands which start a program (in this case you can use `xdg-open` as the program and give it the URL/path as a parameter).

Instead of SMB UNC you probably need to use URLs like `cifs://SERVER/PATH` or `smb://SERVER/PATH`.

Comment: If you are interested in earning some more points, you can head over to the new question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92959/how-do-i-access-my-windows-administrative-share-from-linux).